# Reading a file content in python and using the content to read another corresponding file and then append the information row wise in previous?

Tags: python, bash, awk

I would like to work on the information as below in python. How one should go ahead? If you have other efficient alternatives, please do suggest.

For Example: Following are a set of files providing the information to access another database. In each row the first column and last column value need to be used. i.e For File1: (3 & 1); (1 & 2); (3 & 5); (64 & 7).. Similarly for File2: (5 & 14); (1 & 15) and so on...

```
The content of File1 is:
3       -57.5268        2       -58.1491    1
1       -19.5916        1       -19.5916    2
3       -39.2905        3       -41.498     5
64      -90.3904        35      -92.1006    7
9       -82.2358        3       -83.2294    8
so on... huge file.

The content of File2 is:
5       -555.5268       5       -5328.1491  14
1       -19.5334916     3       -1529.5916  15
3       -39.2905        3       -41.498     16
64      -90.3904        35      -92.1006    17
9       -83.2358        64      -823.2294   19
so on... huge file.

The content of File#i...goes on...
```

So now, in this, these values of File1 (3 & 1); (1 & 2); (3 & 5); (64 & 7) acts as an index for other database where second value i.e 1 in (3 & 1) or 7 in (64 & 7) acts as index for files lingFile#i.txt and other one i.e 3 in (3 & 2) or 64 in (64 & 7) retrieves the values in line number 3 & 64 of the files lingFile#i.txt respectively.

```
The content of lingFile#i.txt
A
B
C
D
E
and so on...
```

And thereafter the original files Files1.txt or Files2.txt... with these two retrieved informations have to be updated as below.

```
The content of File1 is:
3       -57.5268        2       -58.1491    1    A
1       -19.5916        1       -19.5916    2    B
3       -39.2905        3       -41.498     5    C
64      -90.3904        35      -92.1006    7    D
9       -82.2358        3       -83.2294    8    E
so on... huge file.

The content of File2 is:
5       -555.5268       5       -5328.1491  14    F
1       -19.5334916     3       -1529.5916  15    G
3       -39.2905        3       -41.498     16    H
64      -90.3904        35      -92.1006    17    I
9       -83.2358        64      -823.2294   19    J
so on... huge file.

and continued...
```

Comment: How large are the ling_file_#.text files? How many files and lines? This sort of random-access indexing means pretty much the only efficient approach is to preloaded the file contents into a lookup table.

Comment: @HughBothwell_ling_file_#.txt contains few thousands of lines and there are around 20K such files.

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash` or `awk`?

Comment: @Jdamian If somebody can suggest me better way to do this in bash/Awk other than python?

Comment: Can you reduce this to a briefer example with simpler text and/or file names? All this `File_A_1: A_1[3,1]` stuff is confusing enough that some people (e.g. me!) won't bother to try to understand your question and so won't be able to help you answer it. And get rid of the "in Python" text if you don't care whether you use python or not - this is almost certainly trivial in awk.

Comment: @EdMorton_ I am sorry for the confusion. I am editing it for better clarity. Thanks for your kind suggestion.